# How to sync android database with web database?

Tags: android, database, authentication, synchronization

Hi I want to sync android database with web database, my scenario is:

I want to make an android app dictionary. The dictionary words are added by web forms and the user android consume those words. In the Android application I have the historical of words that the user displayed and data of their studies, that should be synchronized online in case of change user phone or him have multiple devices.

My question is how to do that:

**I need authentication or can get the User's google account to identify him?**

**How should I synchronize these two databases?**

**If I use Backup API i can get the same data in diferents devices?**

Answer (score 0):

1. I need authentication or can get the User's google account to identify him?
    That's your decision. You could even provide both methods. Some people don't want to share everything with Google, others don't care. If you want to create your own authenticator read the [Udinic blog post](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) about it.
2. How should I synchronize these two databases?
    You need a sync adapter in Android and a receiving service in your web application. In the Udinic blog there is also a [tutorial about sync adapters](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/). On server side you could create a [REST service](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) for example.
3. If I use Backup API i can get the same data in differents devices?
    The Backup API doesn't seem to be the right choice as it [only restores data during the initial setup](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html) and I assume you want to synchronize the data all the time.